# unable to open app deployed on openshift

Tags: java, angularjs, git, netbeans, openshift

I have deployed using netbeans to openshift. I have committed the changes and push it to git url provided by openshift, but when I try to open it gives 404 error. The default `index.html` page of openshift is loaded instead of my app.

In my local machine, I am opening the url into local host like this:

`http://localhost:8089/BGR3/#/home`

Openshift app link: http://bgr3-management999.rhcloud.com/

web.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
     version="3.1">
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            30
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>

    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>Default.html</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

Context file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Context path="/BGR3"/>
```

Angular stateprovider:

```
myApp.config(function ($stateProvider, $locationProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $httpProvider) {

    // For any unmatched url, redirect to /login
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("home");

    var header = {
        templateUrl: 'views/header.html',
        controller: function ($scope) {
        }
    };

    var footer = {
        templateUrl: 'views/footer.html',
        controller: function ($scope) {
        }
    };
    // Now set up the states 
    $stateProvider
            .state('home', {
                url: "/home",
                views: {
                    header: header,
                    content: {
                        templateUrl: 'views/home.html',
                        controller: function ($scope) {
                        }
                    },
                    footer: footer
                }
            })
            .state('about-us', {
                url: "/about-us",
                views: {
                    'header': header,
                    'content': {
                        templateUrl: 'views/about-us.html',
                        controller: function () {
                        }
                    },
                    'footer': footer
                },
//                data: {
//                    requiresLogin: true
//                }
            })
            .state('products', {
                url: "/products",
                views: {
                    'header': header,
                    'content': {
                        templateUrl: 'views/our-products.html',
                        controller: function () {
                        }
                    },
                    'footer': footer
                },
//                data: {
//                    requiresLogin: true
//                }
            })
            .state('contact-us', {
                url: "/contact-us",
                views: {
                    'header': header,
                    'content': {
                        templateUrl: 'views/contact-us.html',
                        controller: function () {
                        }
                    },
                    'footer': footer
                },
//                data: {
//                    requiresLogin: true
//                }
            }).state('faqs', {
                url: "/faqs",
                views: {
                    'header': header,
                    'content': {
                        templateUrl: 'views/FAQS.html',
                        controller: function () {
                        }
                    },
                    'footer': footer
                },
//                data: {
//                    requiresLogin: true
//                }
            });
    $locationProvider.html5Mode({
        enabled: false,
        requireBase: true
    });
});
```

What am I missing here?

Note: I am using tomcat as server to run the app in local system and on openshift.

Answer (score 0):

**In OpenShift, your applications need to use OpenShift Environment Variables to deploy.**

*What is Happening Here?*

1. You first created apllication with selected cartridge.
2. OpenShift adds default template to get application up and running.
3. You run application at localhost, it runs.
4. ? (See Highlight below)
5. Now you commit and push it back to your app workspace.

*Why is default page showing instead of deployed code?*

- Application did not able to start app and revert back to previous version (which is OpenShift default template).
- So, OpenShift default page is shown.

*What to do now ?*

> You need to configure your app to use OpenShift Environment Variables for Tomcat before deployment (At Step 4 above).

*OpenShift Environment Variables for Tomcat:*

```
OPENSHIFT_JBOSSEWS_IP          -   The IP address used to bind EWS
OPENSHIFT_JBOSSEWS_HTTP_PORT   -   The EWS listening port
OPENSHIFT_JBOSSEWS_JPDA_PORT   -   The EWS JPDA listening port
JAVA_OPTS_EXT                  -   Appended to JAVA_OPTS prior to invoking the Java VM
```

Further Reading: [Tomcat Environment Variables](https://developers.openshift.com/servers/tomcat/environment-variables.html)